# Is this a shopping/list question?

Tags: discussion

The billing software I use to keep track of my hours/clients/invoices etc. is no longer supported by the manufacturer, and I have to find something else. Is it off-topic here to ask for a suggestion? While it's not strictly about writing, anyone who writes/edits for a living in any capacity does have to keep track of money.

Comment: Maybe better at [money.se]?

Comment: @MattEllen I did a quick skim, but that SE is about *personal* finance. This is really a "small business/sole proprietor" question, and I know there are other people in that situation on this board.

Comment: You can ask about "sole proprietorship: bookkeeping". But, if you feel it's not the right place, that's fine. I don't actually use that SE.

Comment: It's off-topic and a list question. Have you tried chat?

Comment: @JohnSmithers ooh, chat is a good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a case of [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/162102) -- in this case, you're asking what's the best way to manage your billing *as a writer*, but the "as a writer" part isn't actually important to the question.  You could ask the same question "as a contract programmer", "as a plumber", "as a private flight instructor", or whatever and you'd get the same answers.  So my instinct would be that it's off-topic, quite aside from whether it's a list question.

However, if there *are* aspects of the question that are specific to writers, a question that focuses on those particular issues could be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new SE site specifically for Software Recommendations.

Could be useful.

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)